# Scraping tbody class object in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest, rselenium

I am completely new to web scraping with R and I would like to scrape the following table (image) that behaves as tbody. If I run the following code, I see only headlines, without the data (Website in Czech).

I should be getting the time, price, volume and volume in CZK for placed orders there.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

PSE_Page <- "https://www.pse.cz/detail/CZ0003519753?tab=detail-trading-data" 
Page <- read_html(PSE_Page)

Our_table <- Page %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
  xml2::xml_find_all("//div[contains(@class, 'stock-table large-table small-text page-block-negative-margin table-container js-swipe-icon')]") %>% 
  rvest::html_text()

Our_table
```

Output:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysv9j.png) "\n                Čas\n                            Cena\n                           Celkový objem\n                            Celkový objem\n     **

Can somebody help? Thanks a lot!!!

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to *which* table you'd like to extract. Can you perhaps edit your post to include a screenshot of the website and highlight which part you're interested in?

Comment: I don't see that table anywhere when I go to https://www.pse.cz/detail/CZ0003519753?tab=detail-trading-data. Can you clarify? On a more general note: If you address a comment (and edit your post) it is usually helpful to ping the person who left the original comment. If you had pinged me in a comment with @MauritsEvers I would've been notified; this makes timely communication a lot easier.

Comment: @MauritsEvers alright thanks.

Comment: Still not clear which table you're referring to. I can't see anything similar to what you show if I go to the website you give. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MauritsEvers if you go to the bottom, it is the bottom table to the left at this page: https://www.pse.cz/detail/CZ0003519753?tab=detail-trading-data

Comment: @MauritsEvers I just checked and it should be available as we speak.

Comment: How odd. I've posted a screenshot of what I see when I follow the URL. There's no table similar to the one you're showing. Do I need to follow another link?

Answer (score 1):

The table you're referring to is not a static table. It is dynamic, since you can iteract with it, e.g. sorting the table. So you can't scrape the information with rvest. I'm really no expert in dynamic web scraping, but this code snippet extracts the data. I use a web browser via the RSelenium package that can be controlled from within R to receive the dynamic content of that table. There are probably much better solutions out there to do this job, though.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(dplyr)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 8787L)
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate("https://www.pse.cz/detail/CZ0003519753?tab=detail-trading-data")
page <- XML::htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])

remDr$close()

header <- XML::xpathSApply(page, "/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/table/thead", XML::xmlValue)
table <- XML::xpathSApply(page, "/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody", XML::xmlValue)

header <- read.table(text=header, sep = "\n", strip.white = T) %>% unlist %>% as.character()
body <- read.table(text=table, sep = "\n", strip.white = T) 
header[3] <- "Total Turnover pcs"
header[4] <- "Total Turnover CZK"

data.frame(lapply(split(body$V1, paste(header)), as.character))

#     Price     Time Total.Turnover.CZK Total.Turnover.pcs
# 1 95,00 % 12:00:25     CZK 780,333.33        800,000 pcs
# 2 95,00 % 12:00:08     CZK 292,625.00        300,000 pcs
# 3 95,00 % 12:00:08     CZK 195,083.33        200,000 pcs
```

Comment: Hi @satesrah, thanks for the proposal, the problem is, that this misses the table with the timestamps completely and I cannot retrieve it through this solution :( (I mean the table with 12:00:13, 95% 500 000 ks, 487 638,89 Kč ...). Maybe it is the table 4 which cannot be loaded through the solution?

Comment: @Michael Sorry, it wasn't clear to me, which table you meant. This makes it a little more complicated, but I updated my answer.

Comment: As of late, it says I have no java development kit. Have you encountered this by chance @satesrah?

Comment: @Michael You can google for how to install the JDK on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

## for this xpath='html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr'

## I just skip the tbody from the xpath

header <-
html_elements(xpath='/html/body/div[1]/table')
header \n
{xml_nodeset (1)}
<table><tr><td width="100%">   <div id="logo">     <table width="100%"><tr><td valign="top">        <a href="https://www.m "

space  space  space

header<-  html_elements(xpath='/html/body/div[1]/table/tr')

> header \n
> {xml_nodeset (1)}
> <tr/><td width="100%">    <div id="logo">      <table width="100%"><tr>\n<td valign="top">            <a href="https://www.maizegdb ."